# ¿Es posible crear graficas de acuerdo a cada fila?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, google-colab

Me gustaria graficar la serie de tiempo de acuerdo a cada una de las filas que tengo agrupadas, en este caso por dias, hasta ahora este es el codigo que tengo, he intentado con varios tipos de bucles **for** sin embargo la mayoria me da error en todos los sentidos.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv("/content/latency por fecha2.csv")

df["column1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["column1"])
df = df.set_index("column1")
df = df.resample("D").mean().dropna()

for i in df:
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
    plt.title(i)
    plt.plot(df[i])
```

[Grafica_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzeow.png)

la tabla se refleja de esta manera.

```
              latency
column1               
2022-08-29  139.381516
2022-09-05  139.517185
2022-09-12  140.056960
2022-09-19  138.720861
2022-10-03  139.683136
```

Pero hasta ahora sigue apareciendo en una sola grafica, he buscado otras alternativas y solo encuentro que se grafica por columnas, aun no doy para que grafique segun el orden de fila.

En este caso busco que se grafiquen las 5 filas en varias graficas segun su fecha ya sea de linea o de barras, la siguiente imagen es un ejemplo de como quisiera que aparezca.

[Grafica_2: Ejemplo de salida](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Wgm.png)

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, aun estoy empezando en este mundo de ciencia de datos y se me da dificil algunas cosas tan sencillas.

Comment: ¿Ese ejemplo de datos son todos los que utilizas? Es decir, quieres graficar únicamente un punto en cada gráfica? ¿Cómo esperas el resultado? Por favor agrega un ejemplo del resultado esperado

Comment: Si, de hecho justo debajo coloque una imagen de ejemplo llamado **Grafica_2: Ejemplo de salida**  de como es que me gustaria que apareciera.